# An autocompleting combobox

Tags: tcl, tk-toolkit

I'm trying to extend the behaviour of ttk::combobox to make it behave like the Google search box in my browser - i.e. I'd like it to drop down automatically and limit the entries in the listbox to those which match the string that I've typed in so far. Ultimately, I'd like to select the part of the string that's been autocompleted so that the next character the user types will cause it to be deleted and re-start the matching process.

I found the page on the [Tcler's wiki](http://wiki.tcl.tk/15780), but that appears to select the entry with the letter just typed, which isn't what I want. (Consider a user selecting from a list of US States. When they type A, I want the selection to be limited to Alabama, Alaska, Arizona and Arkansas; when they then type an L, the list should be limited to Alabama and Alaska. The code on the wiki would select Alabama when the user types A, then Louisiana when they type L.)

I tried defining a few bindings on the ttk::combobox, but gave that up - to be honest, I can't remember why - and have tried to extend the behaviour of a ttk::entry to cover it.

After borrowing liberally from ttk/combobox.tcl I've managed to post a listbox and to limit the entries in the listbox, but am having big problems now that I've added bindings to make the up and down arrows alter the selection. To be precise, the selected item is moved happily, but *some* of the time when the entry widget loses focus, the whole application hangs up and my tclsh soaks up all the CPU.

I'm developing using ActiveTcl 8.6 on both Windows and Linux and the code seems to behave the same on both platforms, although I haven't tried on Linux since I first saw it *not* hanging in Windows. I'd be very happy to share my code, but since the demo script runs to about 450 lines, I wouldn't read it myself if someone else posted that much.

Can anyone help by asking the right question to set off a lightbulb for me? The problem feels like a timing problem, but I've no idea where to start trying to track it down.

Many thanks.

**Edit** I've been racking my brain, and I think the reason I abandonned the attempt to extend ttk::combobx was because there were already a large number of bindings in place, and some did things that I didn't want. The current effort uses a *validatecommand* on the entry widget and Key-Up, Key-Down, FocusIn and FocusOut bindings.

Current code is on pastebin [here](http://pastebin.com/f0q2gRFS).

Comment: have you considered adding a grab on the entry widget when the listbox is visible? That should prevent the widget from losing focus.

Comment: Firstly, I _haven't_ considered putting a grab on the entry widget. I haven't really thought about grabs, other than being very scared of them since hanging up the whole of my Linux box in an early attempt when the listbox got focus and the entry widget was grabbed (or vice versa). Would a grab/focus problem lead to 100% CPU utilisation?

Comment: I don't think a grab/focus problem would cause 100% cpu, but without seeing your code it's impossible to say for sure.

Comment: @nurdglaw Maybe you could private pastebin it and link it to here, update as and when required, and lastly, remove it from pastebin when you're done.

Comment: That sounds like a plan, Jerry. What is pastebin?

Comment: @nurdglaw It's like a host for codes/text http://pastebin.com. I think you'll have to make an account to be able to edit and delete it later though. I keep one account just to share code sometimes ^^

Comment: OK, if I've got this right, my code is on pastebin at http://pastebin.com/f0q2gRFS (Sorry, can't get the hang of links in comments :-( )

Comment: If you change the binding tags (with `bindtags`) you can write your own completely new set of bindings without interfering. The down-side? You have to write your own full set of bindings.

Comment: Thakns for the `bindtags` tip. However, I'd like to persist with my souped-up `ttk::entry` widget approach for now. I've clearly made some mistake with what I've done and I fear that if I go back to trying to extend `ttk::combobox` I'll be letting myself in for a lot of work _and_ may well make the same mistake again. I'm aware of three other problems - there's a vestigial border around the popdown window; the scrollbar isn't displayed when required; Key-Escape isn't handled - but I think the hang is the most serious problem and am trying to sort it out first.

Answer (score 2):

Well, that was embarrassing!

I took another look at [the code on the wiki](http://wiki.tcl.tk/15780) and discovered that it did the thing I most wanted. It doesn't post the listbox, but it does autocomplete, and if you attempt to navigate the (unposted) listbox, by pressing Key-Up or Key-Down, it starts off with the appropriate item highlighted.

That's quite enough for what I need; if I decide I really *must* have the listbox posted, I can see about that at the time. (Given my bad experience trying to roll my own, however, I suspect that I'll just live with this.)

Many thanks for the forebearance and suggestions.

Comment: Woah, haha, glad that you had it sorted out :)